# Removing trailing spaces in <af:inputText>

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am fairly new to the JDeveloper, and I wondering if the JDeveloper comes with a preset configuration setting that lets you remove any trailing spaces from the given string. After, I add an additional space to my string inside `<af:inputText>`, the search displays 0 results. I know you can use TRIM to get rid of the spaces, but is there any way I can fix this problem without making any changes to the query?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do it in java before executing the sql?

Comment: I am looking for a built-in feature.(if it exists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636360/jsf-trinidad-trinputtext-trimming This may help